# Cargar datos al renderizar un componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, local-storage, react-hooks

tengo una duda, cómo podría hacer que carguen los datos de localStorage en estados al renderizar un componente. Tengo una vista llamada MainForm donde se ejecuta una función que guarda los datos en firebase y posteriormente guarda el uid y la data en localStorage

```
    const saveData = () => {
        db.collection('user').add({
            brand: brand.brand,
            city: selectedCity,
            model: model.model,
            timestamp: Date.now()
        })
        .then((docRef) => {
            localStorage.setItem('docRef', docRef.id)
            console.log("Document written");
        }).then(() => {
            const getRef = localStorage.getItem('docRef')
            db.collection("prospects").doc(getRef).onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(doc.data()))
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error("Error adding document: ", error));
    }
```

después pasa a otro componente llamado Rates en el que quiero que cargue los datos de localStorage en estados para poder renderizar el contenido, lo estoy haciendo de este modo:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const getRef = localStorage.getItem('docRef')
        setDocRef(getRef)
        const getData = localStorage.getItem('data')
        const parseData = JSON.parse(getData)
        setData(parseData)
    }, [])
```

pero no renderiza porque no obtiene los datos, y en la consola primero me aparecen los console.log de Rates, y hasta después de esos me sale el del MainForm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría ayudarme para saber qué es lo que puedo hacer o qué estoy haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado async/await en el método que obtiene los datos de Firebase? Por lo que parece, se está actualizando la página antes de que se obtenga el dato de Firebase, por eso devuelve undefined, después null y, por último, el mensaje.

Comment: Podrías hacer una variable de estado `useState()` para controlar cuando finaliza la llamada a Firebase. Por ejemplo, `const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true)`. Luego muestras el componente `Rates` únicamente cuando sea falso (al acabar la llamada haces un `setIsLoading(false)`).

Comment: Estaba checando lo que tengo y pensé que el problema tal vez es como tengo el botón que ejecuta la función, lo tengo dentro de un Link que envía al siguiente componente: `<Link to='/planes'><button onClick={saveData}>COTIZAR</button></Link>` hay algún modo en que esto pueda cambiarse si es que esto genera el problema? Lo intenté con `History.push('/planes')` pero solo me refresca la página

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez lo intenté con async/await y tuve el mismo resultado

Comment: Te recomiendo que saques el `button` del `Link`, el cambio de URL lo puedes hacer dentro del `saveData()` con `history.push('/planes')` y usando el HOC `withRouter` del paquete `react-router-dom`.

Comment: Mmm creo haber tenido un problema similar en algún momento. Prueba a setear el docRef completo en el `localStorage` e imprimelo para ver que te trae. Me huele que falla al intentar acceder a `docRef.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer la redirección a `/planes` dentro de tu función `saveData()` puedes hacerlo utilizando el HOC `withRouter` del paquete `react-router-dom`.

Por ejemplo:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = (props) => {
    const { history } = props

    const saveData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() // para que no recargue la página

        // tu código de saveData()

        history.push('/planes')
    }

    return <button onClick={saveData}>Guardar datos</button>
}

export default withRouter(App)
```

Es necesario que tengas instalado el paquete [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

Comment: gracias, lo intenté así y solo refresca la página o me sigue regresando null

Comment: Asegúrate de renderizar el componente Rates únicamente cuando haya finalizado la llamada a Firebase, usando variables de estado `useState()` por ejemplo.

Comment: Cuando dices que te refresca la página, ¿a qué tipo de refresco te refieres? ¿Te sitúa en la nueva URL sin refrescar la aplicación o ves que te vuelve a cargar todo?

Comment: Vuelve a cargar todo, se refresca y me deja exactamente en el mismo lugar con el form que se había llenado vacío

Comment: ¿Lo tienes en un `form`? Esto explicaría que te recargue la página. Actualizo mi código.